# Programmatically create ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I followed [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/01/create-frame-animation-with.html) to create a simple animation.

The example creates manually an `ImageView` in the main layout, having a resource like this `android:src="@anim/anim_android`

The problem is, when I make a dynamic `ImageView`, and I set the resource like this `myImageView.setImageResource(R.anim.anim_android);`, the animation doesn't work, just views the first image of the sequence.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you sould start the animation from you `imageView` :

```
myImageView.setImageResource(R.anim.anim_android);
final AnimationDrawable myAnimationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)myImageViewn.getDrawable();

myImageView.post(
new Runnable(){

  @Override
  public void run() {
   myAnimationDrawable.start();
  }
});
}
```

**EDIT : i think you didn't add the `ImageView` to your Layout ( `contentView` of your `Activity` ) ; try this :**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout rootLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rootLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        ImageView myAnimation = new ImageView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsImage = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsImage.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        myAnimation.setLayoutParams(paramsImage);
        myAnimation.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.anim_android));
        rootLayout.addView(myAnimation);

        setContentView(rootLayout);


        final AnimationDrawable myAnimationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)myAnimation.getDrawable();

        myAnimation.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                myAnimationDrawable.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I am already doing this. But didn't post the whole code to avoid distraction.

Comment: @khalafnt : i think you didn't add your imageView in your layout, i've created a demo now and i've tested it and it works , see my edits

Comment: You were right. I didn't add it to the layout. :D thanks for your help. Just what I needed.